# Different behavior in connecting to port 0 in windows 2008 32/64 bit

Tags: tcp, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, winsock

When I run the below code in windows 2008 32 bit server, program flow goes to sckTest_Error() when connect() is called.

But when I run the same code in windows 2008 64 bit server, RTE occurs and program flow goes to error:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
On Error GoTo error1
     If (Not (Me.sckTest.State = sckConnected)) Then
        '
        'Log event for outbound client mode connectoin

        If Me.sckTest.State <> sckClosed Then
            Me.sckTest.Close
        End If
        '
        MsgBox "Going to connect"
        Me.sckTest.Connect "127.0.0.1", 0
        MsgBox "Connecting"
       If Me.sckTest.State = sckConnected Then
        MsgBox "Connected"
       End If
        '
    End If
    Exit Sub
error1:
    MsgBox "RTE " & Err.Number
End Sub


Private Sub sckTest_Error(ByVal Number As Integer, 
                          Description As String, 
                          ByVal Scode As Long, 
                          ByVal Source As String, 
                          ByVal HelpFile As String, 
                          ByVal HelpContext As Long, 
                          CancelDisplay As Boolean)
    MsgBox "Error in connecting" & Number
End Sub
```

But I get error as 10049 in both servers. Can any please advice its the problem with my code or server behavior.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to connect to port zero at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port 0 is a special wildcard that allows a socket to bind to a random available ephimeral port. After the binding is successful, you can query the socket to discover which actual port it bound to.  As such, you cannot connect a client socket to port 0, because it is not possible for a server socket to listen on port 0 in the first place.

Comment: Yeah.. I agree with you regards to port 0. Since this is an already developed product, it was already programmed like whatever the port the client configures, system should connect to it. Client might sometimes doesnt need to connect to any port at that time they will set the value as 0. At that time, we are getting the 10049 error. My question here is, why does when 10049 occurs, win2k8 considers it as RTE, whereas win2k3 calls sckTest_Error event?

Comment: There are differences in the way WinSock works internally under different OS versions, that's all. Sometimes the connect error can be detected immediately without attempting to connect to the server, resulting in the RTE case, and other times an error can only be detected after attempting the connection, resulting in the `sckTest_Error` case. There is nothing wrong with your code. Just handle both cases and you will be fine.

Comment: @Santhanam If the client doesn't want to connect to any port, it shouldn't call connect() at all. This isn't making much sense.

Comment: Yeah.. Thanks for your suggestion EJP. Im going to apply fix like you said

Comment: Does anyone knows since when is port zero supported on Windows (which year/win edition)?

Comment: @InTheNameOfScience binding to port 0 to grab an ephermeral port has been supported at least since Winsock 1.0 was introduced in 1992 around the time of Windows 3.1. But TCP socket APIs predate Winsock, so I'm sure the practice of using port 0 goes even further back.